# Control flow and error handling with asynchronous node.js functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, control-flow

**I have a function in which a lot of little processes take place independently, but the result of all of them must go into a final callback. It's not a very unreasonable situation; this kind of code where you don't necessarily know ahead of time what's going to run, when, and for how long is rather common, but after hours in front of this I can't figure out a neat way of doing it. I'm not asking for hours of code time, just a simple explanation on how this could be done.**

The `wrapper` function below completes a series of tasks, asynchronous functions, in a way that it is unclear before execution exactly what will run, when, and how many times. I'm trying to find a neat way of calling a callback (`final callback` comment) once all of them are done completing, if they didn't fail first, but exit the wrapper function immediately on failure. An **example** of this type of situation would be something like that below.

```
// Definition for wrapper function
function wrapper(callback) {
    asyncfunction1();
    for(/*conditions*/) {
        asyncfunction2();
    }
    asyncfunction3(function(results) {
        asyncfunction4(results);
        for(res in results) {
            asyncfunction5(res);
        }
    });
}

// Call to wrapper function
wrapper(function(err) {                // final callback
    if (err) console.log("Failure");
    else console.log("Success");
});
```

The `wrapper` holds a series of functions (`asyncfunction#()`) which must all be completed successfully for the callback to be called as `callback(false)`. If any one fails, the callback is called then and there as `callback(true)` and the whole wrapper exits, without closing the process.

**My stumbling blocks:**

- Is there a way to call the callback upon exit from the wrapper function using a built-in event?
- Is there a native way to exit the wrapper function from several functions deep into it without killing the whole process?

Comment: I'm not 100% understood your question but you may check `async.js` module. It's a async flow control library. You can let it run several async functions and invoke the final callback with aggregated result, or error if any of them failed.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't really matter, it's more of an example. The idea is that the function being examined has a few asynchronous functions within it, that can either fail or succeed, but it is unknown exactly how many times any one of those functions will be called. If any of them fail, a failure callback should be called. If all of them succeed, a success callback should be called.

Comment: The main problem is obviously that one doesn't know "what, when, and how many times" something runs. Is there a certain time window within which the functions have to run? If all running functions have completed, does that mean that the whole wrapper is successful or can it happen that another async function kicks in?
My approach would be to let each async function register itself, then keep track of them. But that doesn't work of course if you have absolutely no limits/knowledge of what is happening :)

Comment: The idea is that the overall program is divided into these 'wrappers,' essentially steps in the process. The wrappers need to be sequential, but the async functions in them are independent of each other, and so can run in any order. The problem is picking out the success or failure of the individual functions and responding to them with a callback once they've all run. The async functions are processes, they can run repeatedly, for example when processing sets of data item by item, but their is a time of final completion. It just can't be predicted ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also suggest using async.js and you'll have some nested calls. Async was made for this type of thing - control flow in NodeJS is tricky. There are other packages for it (promises, other asynchronous packages, etc).

An example using async is below. Note that the outer `.series` method could be `.parallel` if your flow can be run in parallel. I like to pass things around in an outer `resultsObj` that carries over to each async call. It can hold arrays, values, objects, etc . . . just a holder.

I am also using the `.series` notation where an object of named functions are passed in, rather than an array of functions. The values passed to the callback are stored, which I've used in asyncFunction4.

```
var resultsObj = {};
async.series( {
  asyncFunction1: function( seriesCb ) {
    //do stuff
    seriesCb();
  },
  asyncFunction2: function( seriesCb ) {
    async.each( yourArray2, function( item, eachCb ) {
      //do stuff
      eachCb();
    }, function( errEach ) {
      resultsObj.someFlag = true;
      seriesCb( errEach );
    } );
  },
  asyncFunction3: function( seriesCb ) {
    callAsyncFunction3( function( results3 ) {
      async.series( {
        asyncFunction4: function( innerSeriesCb ) {
          var results4 = "yes";
          innerSeriesCb( results4 );
        },
        asyncFunction5: function( innerSeriesCb ) {
          async.each( yourArray5, function( item, eachCb ) {
            //do stuff
            eachCb();
          }, function( errEach ) {
            innerSeriesCb( errEach );
          } );
        }
      }, function( innerSeriesErr, innerSeriesResults ) {
        console.log("Result value of async4 was " + innerSeriesResults.asyncFunction4 );
        seriesCb( innerSeriesErr, innerSeriesResults );
      } );
    } );
  }
}, function( seriesErr, seriesResults ) {
  if ( seriesErr ) console.log( "Failure" );
  else console.log( "Success.  results=" + JSON.stringify( resultsObj ) );
} );
```

EDIT: One more thing. You'll notice how large this control skeleton is already. And that's without code. Break apart your methods and have them accept (and use) the typical NodeJS `callback(err)` or `callback(err, results)` style. Then in your async flows, call them in that shorter way. It will just keep this large controlling file a little more manageable.

```
function doSomething( input1, input2, callback ){
  if( input1 === input2 ) return callback( new Error("Cannot be equal") );
  callback( null, "Success ");
}

async.series( {
  asyncFunction1: function( seriesCb ) {
    doSomething( 1, 2, seriesCb );
  }
}, function( seriesErr, seriesResults ) {
  if ( seriesErr ) console.log( "Failure" );
  else console.log( "Success" );
} );
```